# Will billingClient.launchBillingFlow return a synchronized value when I use Google in-app purchase with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

The Code A comes from the official Google in -app purchase [article](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#launch).

I believe that `billingClient.launchBillingFlow` is executed asynchronously, making the `val billingResult` an asynchronous value. Therefore, Code A should be enclosed within a `suspend` function.

In contrast, Code B, which is written by me, compiles and runs successfully. It appears that `val launchResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)` is a synchronized value.

What could be the issue with my code?

**Code A**

```
val activity : Activity = ...;

val productDetailsParamsList = listOf(
    BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()   
        .setProductDetails(productDetails)     
        .build()
)

val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
    .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
    .build()

val billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
```

**Code B**

```
fun launchPurchase(
        activity: Activity     
    ) {        
         if (billingClient.isReady) {
             val productDetailToBuy = _allProductWithDetails.value[productIDToPurchase]
             if (productDetailToBuy != null) {
                 val productDetailsParams = BillingFlowParams
                     .ProductDetailsParams
                     .newBuilder()
                     .setProductDetails(productDetailToBuy)
                     .build()

                 val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                     .newBuilder()
                     .setProductDetailsParamsList(listOf(productDetailsParams))
                     .build()

                 val  launchResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
                 if (launchResult.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                     _displayMessage.value= "Error: "+launchResult.debugMessage
                 }

             } 
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `billingResult` from `val billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)` is indeed synchronous, but there is a key difference.

This `billingResult` is the result of *launching* the billing flow (that is a synchronous operation), but not of the billing flow itself. Conversely, the flow itself is asynchronous, and *its* result is delivered to the `onPurchasesUpdated` callback. These two instances of `billingResult` may differ.

If you successfully launch the billing flow and make a purchase, then `BillingResponseCode.OK` is returned right away as the result of *launching* the flow, and another `BillingResponseCode.OK` is returned after the purchase is made.

If you change your mind and close the purchase dialog after launching the flow, the second `billingResult` will be `BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED`, even though the result of the *launching* remains the same as in the previous example. And even if the dialog shows that the item has already been purchased, or you don't have an active internet connection, the *launching* result will still be `BillingResponseCode.OK`.

But if you don't have Play Market installed at all (or have disabled it in the Settings, via adb, or otherwise), both instances of `billingResult` will yield `BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED`.

In fact, I believe the first 'synchronous' result may not be necessary; the result from the `onPurchasesUpdated` callback should suffice.